# IE foreach: Объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
function getAllElements() {
   var elements = [];
   ['input','select'].forEach(function (nodeName) {
       elements.push.apply(elements , document.getElementsByTagName(nodeName));
   });
   return elements;
}

document.onclick=new function(){
var buff = getAllElements().map(function (el) {
        return el.name;
    }).join();
    alert(buff);
     }
}
```

IE жалуется на строку  `['input','select'].forEach(function (nodeName)` {

> "Объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод"

подскажите решение проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если без лишних скриптов, то не используйте методы из es5. Или же [реализуйте их сами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) :

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18
// Reference: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {

  Array.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {

    var T, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined");
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 7. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as the this value and
        // argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }
    // 8. return undefined
  };
}
```

Comment: спасибо, ошибок нет. Но теперь возвращает пустой результат, будто ничего не найдено
http://pastebin.com/sxFEztf4 что не так?

Comment: Ваша реализация map работает [нормально](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/qo77zhzv/). Проблема скорей всего в функции getAllElements.

Answer (score 1):

Да - [shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) а еще можно использовать [html5 shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim) и `document.querySelectorAll('select,input')`

вот компиляция этих двух : https://github.com/termi/ES5-DOM-SHIM

Comment: спасибо, но нужно решение без левых скриптов.

Comment: что значит "без левых" ? ваш скрипт что-ли "правый" ?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог polyfill отсюда [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill)

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
   NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```